# What determines how many times map() will get called?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a text file and a parser that will parse each line(s) and store into my customSplitInput, I do the parsing in my custom FileInputFormat phase so my splits are custom. Right now, I have 2 splits and within each split contains a list of my data.

But right now, my mapper function is getting called repeatedly on the same split. I thought the mapper function will only get called based on the number of splits you have?

I don't know if this applies but my custom InputSplit returns a fixed number for getLength() and an empty string array for getLocation(). I am unsure of what to put in for these.

```
@Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, ArrayWritable> createRecordReader(
            InputSplit input, TaskAttemptContext taskContext)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        logger.info(">>> Creating Record Reader");
        CustomRecordReader recordReader = new CustomRecordReader(
                (EntryInputSplit) input);
        return recordReader;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`map()` is called once for every record from the `RecordReader` in (or referenced by) your `InputFormat`. For example, `TextInputFormat` calls `map()` for every line in the input, even though there are usually many lines in a split.

Comment: I added my record reader create function. It just creates a recordreader with my custom split and return

Comment: Ok. Does my answer answer your question?

Comment: Sorry but your answer doesn't make sense with my code. My createRecordReader only returns a recordReader with 1 split that contains a list of 25 items. But the mapper function gets called way more than 25 times. My CustomInputFormat creates only 2 splits so, again, each recordReader will have 1 of those split.